# How to force logged in user's id token to refresh firebase from firebase admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

After changing user's customClaims, I want them to reflect immediately on the logged in client. How can I do that from nodejs admin?

I know how to do that from the client side using `auth.idToken(true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to force a client to refresh from the Admin SDK. The client itself will have to call the `getIdToken(true)` to refresh its token.

If you want to force a refresh, you will have to send a signal from the Admin SDK to the relevant client, probably through something like Firebase Cloud Messaging, or the Realtime Database/Cloud Firestore. The client can then, upon receiving that signal, refresh its token.

Comment: That's what I'm going to do. Thanks Frank.